# Hooking KiUserExceptionDispatcher- can't find typedef anywhere?

Tags: c++, winapi, protector

I'm writing a file protector that is similar to armadillo.  So, I want to implement some kind of "nanomites" for anti-dump protection.

However, instead of opening my own process I've decided to hook `KiUserExceptionDispatcher`.

The problem is I don't know what is being passed to `KiUserExceptionDispatcher`nor am I sure how to continue after I have determined the exception type is a `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` exception.

I've tried searching Google, but to no avail.  All I find are results for `KiDispatchException`, which is hooked in rootkits.

Can someone provide me a typedef of this function, and tell me what I would do to continue after determining it was indeed a `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` exception? Would I call `NtContinue` after modifying the EIP context?

Or if this is not simple as I think it is, should I just stick to the armadillo style? Debugging my own process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The closest thing to documentation is going to be this MSJ article:
[A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32 Structured Exception Handling](https://web.archive.org/web/20030810214010/http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx)

Which provides this as *sample* for basic prototype (from [Figure 14](https://web.archive.org/web/20080914033503/http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exceptiontextfigs.htm#fig14)):

```
KiUserExceptionDispatcher( PEXCEPTION_RECORD pExcptRec, CONTEXT * pContext )
```

In practice, I've also seen instances where the PEXCEPTION_RECORD was in the 3rd parameter and not the first (at least from WinDbg's perspective). There are also potential differences between x86 and x64 implementations.

Is there a reason you can't add an additional exception vector via [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](https://web.archive.org/web/20120413234240/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Additional reading: [Under the Hood: New Vectored Exception Handling in Windows XP](https://web.archive.org/web/20021108024747/http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/01/09/hood/default.aspx)

Comment: On Windows 7 x64, the exception code given to KiUserExceptionDispatcher is stored in the first argument(first argument to be pushed on the stack; third stack element from Ollydbg's perspective).